# Where is my bitcoin

Tags: transactions

So its been almost a month and two transfers I done have yet to reach the address

f2cc94ce66eca7e55108ad0655e66ec1a97c12d05b51e8dd518a669f288de6e4 transID
1GKHoWnZr9vpFjzZas6138fc1QrrAndiHp   address

6f5d6cc00cabf6259852048eef2f8d827b7d43c08da361cec08d67e468c5e1de  trans ID
1BABUhAB7976cP7qVcAEfUrtmitYZYkTw7 address

Please help anyone

Answer (score 1):

Both of the transactions you linked were confirmed in the blockchain a while ago, and their outputs have since been spent. You can see this if you copy/paste the address into a block explorer website and look at the transaction history.

If you own the keys to those two addresses, but did not spend the bitcoins yourself after the transactions into those two addresses, then it seems your wallet may have been compromised and your bitcoins stolen.